# Does Financial services cloud trial org not have standard Campaign object?

Tags: financial-services-cloud

Can anyone guide me if Financial services cloud contains campaign standard object?

I have setup the FSC trial org but can't find the campaign object in it. I also checked out the data model of FSC and unable to find the campaign object. I am attaching the FSC data model picture.[image: FSC Data model]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 versions of the FSC trial org:

- [Enterprise edition trial](https://www.salesforce.com/au/form/signup/financial-services-cloud-trial/?d=70130000002DxK0) which does have campgaign
- [Trailhead edition trial](https://developer.salesforce.com/promotions/orgs/fscplayground) which does not have campaign (assuming watered down for quicker setup and only needs to be used to demo FSC specific features)

FSC is installed as a package in a sales+service cloud org and then FSC is managed by permission sets so the trailhead edition might be something else entirely for the sole purpose of trailhead.

If you have other weird issues a good place to find out why is to ask in the [FSC Chatter Group](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A0000004gQJ) where a product manager might see and respond.

A couple of references to backup my claim regarding that campaign is available for FSC

- An official FSC sheet which has a visual example and includes campaign words on the second page (https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/2366326/2017/2017_collaterals/financial-services-cloud-datasheet.pdf)
- A screenshot of my production org

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_services_cloud_object_reference.meta/financial_services_cloud_object_reference/fsc_api_access_and_usage.htm), Campaign is not part of Financial Services Cloud package. Fields and objects in the package have the FinServ namespace prefix. For example, FinServ__IndividualId__c is a custom field on Account. FinServ__FinancialAccount__c is a custom object. To refer to the standard Salesforce objects, see the [Object Reference for Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/).

Comment: Worth noting - I tried installing a managed package that used Campaigns onto a fresh trial FSC org, and it didn't let me install because the Campaign feature wasn't supported :-/

Comment: I believe this answer is wrong, the reference links you have made are for the objects that are installed with the FSC managed package. FSC is installed over a standard sales+service cloud org. I also have access to a production FSC org and have access to the campaign object.

Comment: I have just found out that there are 2 editions of trial org which is why it might not be appearing if you are using the trailhead trial and not the full enterprise trial, see my answer for links

Answer (score 0):

Campaign will not be part of FSC not any classes/logic is referred. You can add Campaign to your FSC model and customise as required